# How to execute permuted operations of itertools on a Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, foreach, python-itertools

I have the following data frame **test** in Python :

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'id':['F8510004123','A3100002543','Z3510002123'],
                     'product':['retail','retail','others'],
                     'type':['E','E','D'],
                     'quantity':[25,34,150],
                     'nro_ope':[2,3,26],
                     'payments':[[1030.97,1030.97,584.91],[1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1611.14],[1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,500,500,852.95]]
                     })
test.dtypes
```

Represented in tables:

| id | product | types | quantity | nro_ope | payments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F8510004123 | retail | E | 25 | 2 | 1030.97,1030.97,584.91 |
| A3100002543 | retail | E | 34 | 3 | 1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1611.14 |
| Z3510002123 | others | D | 150 | 26 | 1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,500,500,852.95 |

According to the type of data:

**test.dtypes**

Out[449]:

id          object

product     object

type        object

quantity     int64

payments    object

dtype: object

I want to perform the following permuted operation for each of the elements of the column **payments** of the dataframe **test**, with the library **itertools** of Python:

```
  payment_column_1 = [1030.97,1030.97,584.91]
  payment_column_2 = [1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1611.14]
  payment_column_3 = [1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,500,500,852.95]
 
 
  from itertools import permutations
  permuted_operation_1 = [round(abs(a/b -1),3) for a,b in permutations(payment_column_1,2)]
  permuted_operation_2 = [round(abs(a/b -1),3) for a,b in permutations(payment_column_2,2)]
  permuted_operation_3 = [round(abs(a/b -1),3) for a,b in permutations(payment_column_3,2)]
```

output:

`print(permuted_operation_1)`

[0.0, 0.763, 0.0, 0.763, 0.433, 0.433]

`print(permuted_operation_2)`

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
0.0, 0.0]

`print(permuted_operation_3)`

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.0,
0.414, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.0, 0.414, 0.153, 0.153, 0.153, 0.153, 0.706, 0.706]

However, as you can see, I apply this permuted operation from a list, when what I require is from the same data frame **test** create a new column **var_payments** where the array is inserted with the results of the operation for each row that the data frame has,as seen in the following table:

| id | product | types | quantity | nro_ope | payments | var_payments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F8510004123 | retail | E | 25 | 2 | {1030.97,1030.97,584.91} | {0.0, 0.763, 0.0, 0.763, 0.433, 0.433} |
| A3100002543 | retail | E | 34 | 3 | {1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1611.14} | {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} |
| Z3510002123 | others | D | 150 | 26 | {1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,500,500,852.95} | {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.0, 0.414, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.0, 0.414, 0.153, 0.153, 0.153, 0.153, 0.706, 0.706} |

I've made progress with the following, but apparently it's wrong:

```
test['var_payments'] = test['payments'].apply( lambda r:round(abs(a/b -1),3) for a,b in 
permutations (r,2))
```

output:

NameError: name 'r' is not defined

Finally, I need to create the column **flag**, it basically traverses the elements of the newly created column **var_payments**, and if it finds at least two elements are greater than or equal to 0.05, then it is assigned **Yes**, otherwise it would be **No**

| id | product | types | quantity | nro_ope | payments | var_payments | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F8510004123 | retail | E | 25 | 2 | {1030.97,1030.97,584.91} | {0.0, 0.763, 0.0, 0.763, 0.433, 0.433} | Yes |
| A3100002543 | retail | E | 34 | 3 | {1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1611.14} | {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} | No |
| Z3510002123 | others | D | 150 | 26 | {1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,500,500,852.95} | {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.015, 1.015, 0.181, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.0, 0.414, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.504, 0.0, 0.414, 0.153, 0.153, 0.153, 0.153, 0.706, 0.706} | Yes |

How could I do it?

I am attentive to your comments.

Thanks for support.

Comment: supply your dataframe as code in the form of `df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3, etc..]})` so that we can paste it in to our IDE

Answer (score 0):

I got it by creating functions in python :

```
test= pd.DataFrame({'id':['F8510004123','A3100002543','Z3510002123'],
                     'product':['retail','retail','others'],
                     'type':['E','E','D'],
                     'quantity':[25,34,150],
                     'nro_ope':[2,3,26],
                     'payments':[[1030.97,1030.97,584.91],[1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1610.74,1611.14],[1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,1007.52,500,500,852.95]]
                     })

;

def var_payments (x) :
    variation  = [round(abs(a/b -1),3) for a,b in permutations(x,2)]
    return variation 

;

def count_var_pay (x) :
    count = 0
    for element in x:
        if element >= 0.05 :
            count += 1
        else:
             0                    
    return count

;

def flag_var_payments (x) : 
    if x >= 2 :
        return 'Yes'
    else : 
        return 'No'

;

test['var_payments'] = test.payments.apply(lambda x:var_payments(x))

test['count_p'] = test.var_payments.apply(lambda x:count_var_pay(x))

test['flag'] = test.count_p.apply(lambda x:flag_var_payments(x))
```